# iPhone Development with Bluetooth SPP OS 3/4

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, serial-port, profile

I am in the process of developing an iPhone application that communicates with a number of Bluetooth devices that all support Serial Port Profile - well I assume that it is SPP as they show on my MacBook as Serial Port DevB etc.

I understand that iPhone OS 3.x does not support SPP - is that correct?  Does anyone know if that has been "fixed" in OS 4?  I've seen reports of OS 4 supporting keyboards, but is that a locked version of HID, or will SPP be available via the SDK?

Kind Regards,
Nige.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be a locked version of HID, you can track Bluetooth support here:
http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3647