# iPhone 4: set up/use bluetooth SPP

Tags: iphone, bluetooth

How would I program an iPhone app that utilitizes bluetooth SPP to connect to another bluetooth device? I can't find the documentation anywhere.

Thanks so much.

*EDIT*
I guess Mac OS X uses RFCOMM but i can't find anything similar in iphone documentation

Comment: Did you check out Core Bluetooth? http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CoreBluetooth_Framework/CoreBluetooth_Framework.pdf Not sure if that does what you want.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16035166/does-ios-support-bluetooth-spp

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned here:
[iPhone Development with Bluetooth SPP OS 3/4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818627/iphone-development-with-bluetooth-spp-os-3-4)

It's not supported and I doubt they will both supporting it either:
http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3647

I'd love them to support it too, but I just don't think it's going to happen. Because it doesn't help them to sell more gear, it becomes a very low priority.