# Does iOS support Bluetooth SPP?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios4

I want to develop an ios application that communicates with another bluetooth supported device via Bluetooth SPP.

Does iOS support SPP?

I checked iOS supported profiles bu couldn't see anything about SPP..

http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3647

So, is there any other way for using SPP ?

Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, unfortunately Apple (iOS) Bluetooth does not support SPP. In order to make a serial cable communication to an iOS Device you have to use the Authentication CoProcessor. I guess from that reason, Bluetooth does not support Wire Communication Emulation because you will not have the Authentication of the "Genuine iPod Device" iAP Protocol (MFI Specification)